# knowing when to call persist

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 as my ORM, and things are going well, but I've been wondering about the `EntityManager#persist()` method. The ["Persisting entities"](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#title.1.3) documentation says the following about a call to `persist()` for object `X`:

> If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation.

That leads me to believe that `persist()` need only be called when the object is new and has not yet been saved to the database. However, the documentation for the ["Deferred Explicit" change tracking policy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#title.1.2) says:

> ... Doctrine 2 only considers entities that have been explicitly marked for change detection through a call to EntityManager#persist(entity) ...

... which sounds like `persist()` must be called on the object for it to be updated at all. When should `persist()` be called? If only on new objects, is there a significance performance hit to call it anyway whenever an entity is updated and let Doctrine sort out the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the [Deferred Explicit policy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#title.1.2) (it's not the default policy), you need to explicitly call persist() on each modified entity for doctrine to persist them. (Except for cascade-persist associations.)

Doctrine still needs to compare the new value of each property with the original value to know which property to update, so this may have a performance hit if you `persist()` too much entities.

With the [default change tracking policy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#title.1.1) you only need to call persist on entities that are not yet managed by Doctrine (entities that you created with `new`). With this policy, when you call flush() doctrine automatically detects which entities have been updated and need to be persisted.

Comment: Note that when using Deferred Implicit change tracking (the default), Doctrine will compare the original value with the new value for every property (so far the same as Deferred Explicit) for every entity that is in the UnitOfWork, and not just the ones you called `persist()` on.

Comment: Lived half my life until the problem aroused with thought that default policy is Deferred Explicit policy.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation is somewhat misleading. In implicit tracking mode, all entities have a state (managed, removed, detached etc.); entities obtained by `find()` and similar methods (basically everything which is not created with `new`) are already in managed state. On `flush()`, all managed (and removed) entites are checked for changes and, if necessary, updated in the DB.

In explicit tracking mode, there is an additional dirty check list, and `persist()` adds the object (and possibly associated objects, depending on cascade settings) to that list. Only items on the dirty check list are considered for update. The dirty check list is cleared after flushing, so if you do a second flush, and change the same object again, you must call `persist()` once more. (In contrast, the managed state is kept after flush.)

You can check the details for yourself in the [Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php) class; search for `isChangeTrackingDeferredImplicit` / `isChangeTrackingDeferredExplicit` (those are the only places where behavior differs under the two policies).

Comment: I have a detached entity (channel) coming form cached result set that I need to add data to- only affecting data table. Is there any way to persist the channel's data without merging the detached channel?

Comment: @andig, not sure. I take it you are talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102728/doctrine-persisting-detached-entities) - why do you need to persist the channel at all when you really just want to add a new data entity?

Comment: excellent question. I'm working with legacy code and am still new to Doctrine. Will investigate how/if I can persist the ArrayCollection of 'data' directly. If working I'd appreciate a cross-answer so I can vote.