# Symfony 4.3 Multiple ChoiceType can only add values and not remove when using PATCH

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-4.3

Given form:

```
...
        $builder
            ->add('testArray', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => ['ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER'],
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ])
        ;

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TestEntity::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'method' => 'PATCH'
        ]);
    }

...
```

And entity:

```
...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $testArray = [];

    public function getTestArray(): ?array
    {
        return $this->testArray;
    }

    public function setTestArray(?array $testArray): self
    {
        $this->testArray = $testArray;

        return $this;
    }
...
```

When submitting the form by adding values... everything works fine.
But when removing values... the values are not removed, and the setter is never called.

Strangely, switching the form method to GET fixes this.

What's going on?

--- edit ---

Here's a controller that reproduces this issue:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="test_entity_edit", methods={"GET","POST","PATCH"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, TestEntity $testEntity): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(TestEntityType::class, $testEntity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();


            return $this->redirectToRoute('test_entity_index', [
                'id' => $testEntity->getId(),
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('test_entity/edit.html.twig', [
            'test_entity' => $testEntity,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

---- edit ----

Testing using POST this works perfectly. But using PATCH it fails. All other fields update. And adding to the array works. But removing from the array doesn't. I've added the relevant PATCH code above and updated the title to clarify the question.

Comment: Can we see your controller as well ?

Comment: If you dump `$testEntity` after your form submission, has `$testArray` changed as you expect? I have nearly identical code and I'm not seeing this behavior.

Comment: No, after submitting a patch with only `ROLE_USER` in the data, `setTestArray` is not called and `$testEntity` still contains both `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `PATCH` is ambiguous when it comes to arrays and there are various ways of handling the sent data.

Symfony will detect a `PATCH` and not `$clearMissing` when calling `submit()` (not empty the fields in the entity that are missing from the data). When it comes to an array, this is ambigious.

To deal with this I've moved away from using PATCH to update a user entity and moved to this solution [Symfony2: Edit user without having password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856396/symfony2-edit-user-without-having-password)

Which essentially uses two different FormType's one to create the user, and another to edit it. Each form type uses a different validation group. Allowing to edit a user without submitting or clearing the users password.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this it the entirety of your problem, but when you handle your form submit, you are not persisting the entity.

```
$this-getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

is normally written

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($testEntity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#handling-form-submits

Comment: I don't think you need to persist entity's that are already managed by doctrine (Entity's not created with 'new'). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262967/6478568

Comment: Wow, I did not realize that detail about persist. I guess it's in the best practices because it's safe and covers the case of a new object, but it's not necessary in your case. Thanks for the education!